# VSSecondaryInstaller_box error while downloading Visual Studio Community 2015 with update 3 using layout on windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation

Recently, I have tried to download Visual Studio Community 2015 with update 3 using layout command. I have a very good internet connection. Everything was going fine when I ended up with this stated error. I don't know if I can proceed for its installation. Also the error does not state completely about itself. Please help me with this one. Please tell me if I can proceed for its installation.

It is stated as:

**VSSecondaryInstaller_box**: Download of product 'PowerShellToolsV1' failed. Downloaded file failed signature verification and may have been tampered with

[image: This is that error that I am talking about]

The last 2 lines of the log file reads as

```
[09CC:06CC][2017-12-28T09:05:10]i000: MUX:  P9 - Download of product 'PowerShellToolsV1 failed. Downloaded file failed signature verification and may have been tampered with
[09CC:06CC][2017-12-28T09:05:10]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x0, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Comment: Could you please share your layout command and where did you download the VS community 2015 with update 3, I will test it in my side. Meanwhile, you can have a look at this similar issue: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c8ec9cd6-87d2-4b1c-a23b-0f6acaf50f36/visual-studio-enterprise-installer-is-broken-again?forum=vssetup and this doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt653628.aspx to download an earlier version like VS community 2015 RTM version without any updates to have a try.

Comment: @SaraLiu-MSFT I have the web installer named as ```vs_community_u3.exe``` in a folder named ```web_installer```. In the command prompt, I navigated to the web_installer folder and ran ```vs_community_u3.exe /layout "C:/VS2015"```. Then I left the setup to download all the files overnight. When I woke up, I ended up with this error.

Comment: I assume there is a good reason why you don't install the latest version of Visual Studio? (2017). [Visual Studio Download](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/).

Comment: @SiddharthSaraf, I can reproduce this issue in my side, sorry for this inconvenience. Since you have a good network connection, why did you want a offline installer? Now VS 2017 is stable and you can think about to install the VS 2017.

Comment: I have a good but limited(max 1GB/day) internet connection. I have suffered a lot while directly installing VS from web-installer. I researched the net and found that the VS2015 is smaller than VS2017. I ran the layout command for 3-4 nights to download. Another reason is that I am just beginning with UWP development, so I wanted to have a try. Also with this error windows SDKs didn't downloaded which I have now downloaded-and-installed on-the-go from modify option in the setup. All I want to say is that my internet connection can cheat me anytime. That's why I prefer offline setups

Answer (score 1):

Please check this: [Create an offline installation of Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio) and it have improvements to download the offline installer of VS 2017 and you can custom your own offline installer per your requirement, the size will smaller than the whole offline installer of VS 2015 which is over 20GB.

Following the docs as below to confirm the download command like *vs_community.exe --layout c:\vs2017layout --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal --lang en-US* for your development purposes.

[Install Visual Studio 2017 on low bandwidth or unreliable network environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-vs-inconsistent-quality-network)

[Visual Studio Community 2017 workload and component IDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-community)

Comment: what arguments shall I give to download xamarin for android development in layout.The xamarin website is giving the same vs2017 setup

Comment: The workload 'Mobile development with .NET' is used to build cross-platform applications for iOS, Android or Windows using Xamarin, you can use the '--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat' to have a try.